# click event fires twice

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button

I wanted some nice buttons so I use `.button()` in jQuery like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#idBlaBla").button();
});
```

server side:

```
 Private Sub btnSaveVisible_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSaveVisible.ServerClick
```

The problem is that when I click it fires the even twice. It doesn't happen in debug with visual studio 2008. but when the website is online, every buttons with jQuery trigger the event twice.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Where is the event handler attached?

Comment: click event server side in vb.net

Comment: I think you should remove inline `onclick` attribute.

Comment: theres no onclick attribute except when the code is generated. Theres a onclick=" dopostback"

Comment: I still can't find why. Any ideas? plz

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
//call event click or press button
$('#idBlaBla').click();

//listen event
$('#idBlaBla').click(function( event ){
    //your code here...
});

//listen multi events
$('#idBlaBla').bind('click focus blur',function( event ){
    //your code here...
});

//listen new element(append fro example)
$('.div').append( '<a href="" id="idBlaBla">Anchor Button</a>' );
$('#idBlaBla').live('click',function( event ){
    //your code here...
});
```

Comment: Thank you but my code is server side. I just wanted nice buttons and the code is made by jquery ui I think. So when I do .buttons, the functions are linked to my button but I don't know whats functions so I dont know how to call them like this

Comment: why not create an application with "python" interpreter javascriot you, then you run the clicks???

Answer (score 1):

In that case, we can do the following

```
$('selected').unbind('click').bind('click', function (e) {
  add_course(this);
});
```

I had the event firing two times initially, when the page get refreshed it fires four times. It was after many fruitless hours before I figured out with a google search.

I must also say that the code initially was working until I started using the JQueryUI accordion widget.